# Aggregate data based on timestamp in JavaDStream of spark streaming

Tags: java, spark-streaming

I am writing a spark streaming job in java which takes input record from kafka.
Now the record is available in JavaDstream as a custom java object. 
Sample record is :

TimeSeriesData: `{tenant_id='581dd636b5e2ca009328b42b', asset_id='5820870be4b082f136653884', bucket='2016', parameter_id='58218d81e4b082f13665388b', timestamp=Mon Aug 22 14:50:01 IST 2016, window=null, value='11.30168'}`

Now I want to aggregate this data based on min, hour, day and week of the field "timestamp".

My question is, how to aggregate JavaDstream records based on a window. A sample code will be helpful.

Comment: i would say, you have to split the timestamp into min, hour, day and week  field in your timeseries data. then do the aggrgtion.

Comment: What if I want to use window operations, like we do it for dataframes.

Comment: i thought of suggesting that but i am not sure about your usecase. Say for example if you want to have all the strams that are received last X time we  can use the window option.

Comment: I believe that windows option will work based on the datetime, I am not usre how to use timestamp field in it

Comment: Basically, If I could use something like this 
http://blog.madhukaraphatak.com/introduction-to-spark-two-part-5/

But, for this I need to have all data from JavaDstream to DataFrame.
Also, In my use case the requirement is :
Lets say for a particular parameter_id I received 10 records in a minute with different values, then the output should contain :
parameter_id, timestamp(HH:mm), value (aggregated)